# Nightwatch globals variable can't get on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, nightwatch

Why the Nightwatch globals variable can't get on Jenkins?
I added below in the `nightwatch.js`

`"globals_path": "global.js"`

And the test like this

```
module.exports = {
    "@tags": ["jenkins"],
    "Test on jenkins": browser => {
        let TEST_ONE = browser.globals.TEST_ONE;
        console.log(TEST_ONE);
        console.log(browser.globals);
    }
}
```

This is my `globlas.js`

```
module.exports = {
  TEST_ONE: "Hellow world"
};
```

When I run it in local it works well
But it can't get the globals variable on Jenkins
The console on the Jenkins

```
{
  abortOnAssertionFailure: true,
  waitForConditionPollInterval: 500,
  waitForConditionTimeout: 5000,
  throwOnMultipleElementsReturned: false,
  suppressWarningsOnMultipleElementsReturned: false,
  asyncHookTimeout: 10000,
  unitTestsTimeout: 2000,
  customReporterCallbackTimeout: 20000,
  retryAssertionTimeout: 5000,
  reporter: [Function: reporter]
}
```

The console on my local

````
{
  abortOnAssertionFailure: true,
  waitForConditionPollInterval: 500,
  waitForConditionTimeout: 5000,
  throwOnMultipleElementsReturned: false,
  suppressWarningsOnMultipleElementsReturned: false,
  asyncHookTimeout: 10000,
  unitTestsTimeout: 2000,
  customReporterCallbackTimeout: 20000,
  retryAssertionTimeout: 1000,
  reporter: [Function],
  TEST_ONE: 'Hellow world',
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer
Just add this in the Jenkins shell
`#!/bin/sh -l`